Rate of convergence of mollified distributions in Besov spaces with negative regularity
Given a standard mollifier $\rho_\delta$ and a distribution $ u \in B^\alpha_{ p, p}$ with $\alpha<0$, $p \in [1, \infty]$ and $B^\alpha_{p,p}$ is a not-homogeneous Besov space, I'm trying to prove that
$$
\| u-u_\delta \|_{B^{\beta}_{p,p}} \lesssim \delta^{|\beta-\alpha|} \|u\|_{B^{\alpha}_{p,p}}
$$
with $\beta< \alpha$.
If $\alpha>0$ It is possible to procede as in this question to find such estimate and the negative regularity case can be treated by duality, but, as my final objective is to treat pathwise solution of non linear PSDE-s (in the spirit of this paper) I'm looking for a more direct approach (e.g. based on the Littlewood-Paley decomposition of the function).
All the reference I have found only treat the case with positive regularity and I'm wondering if a proof of such kind of estimate already exists and in which way the problem can be tackled.

This isn't true for any fixed Besov norm, you'll have to put a weaker norm on the lhs...
